# how do I blacklist users slugs with friendly id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, friendly-id

I want to use friendly id so that users can have a nice url. However I want to blacklist certain names such as api or admin or curse words. Where do I load the yaml file to do that? in the model?

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried ?

Comment: friendly id has an [initializer](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/initializer.rb) where you can configure reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

Give the following code a try-

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  excluded_words = ["admin", "api"]
  friendly_id_config.reserved_words.concat(excluded_words)
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

Comment: thanks darpa, if I want to let me user have the choice create a slug, how would I go about doing that? At the moment I have it automatically set with their given name

Comment: oh found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989827/user-editable-slugs-with-friendly-id?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_slug_blacklist
  blacklist = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config/blacklist.yml'))
  if blacklist.include?(self.slug)
    self.errors.add :slug, "Please choose to a different slug"  # TO DO USE I18n
  end
end
```