# Usernames clashing with existing routes (FriendlyId)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users of my app are now able to access their profile (`users/show.html.erb`) like so:

```
domain.com/johndoe
```

To make that happen, I used the following code

#### routes.rb:

```
get '/:friendly_id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
```

#### user.rb:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :username, use: [:finders]
validates_uniqueness_of :username
```

#### users_controller.rb:

```
def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:friendly_id])
end
```

The problem is my other routes such as `domain.com/explore` and `domain.com/admin` no longer work since the router thinks they are usernames. Just to clarify, "explore" and "admin" are not user profiles but models of their own.

Now it throws an error like this:

> can't find record with friendly id: "explore"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you add your routes file data?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this solution. In the immediate term, you want to restore functionality to your site, and ensure that users can't override other routes.

1. Move your `friendly_id` route to the bottom of your routes.rb file, below all the other "explore" and "admin" routes. Since routes are parsed from top to bottom, this allows your main routes to take precedence.
2. Secondly, you'll want to look in [FriendlyId's reserved words](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Reserved), to stop users from creating slugs that would leave them unable to access their account. More info [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799735/how-do-i-blacklist-users-slugs-with-friendly-id).

Answer (score 0):

You could try and add the words you'd want to skip in the `config/initializers/friendly_id.rb` in the `config.reserved_words` array:

```
config.reserved_words = %w(new edit .... explore admin)
```

And restart the server.